# How to find out where to download python module

Tags: python, file, module

I have anaconda installed but started a tutorial which uses the IDLE. I'll download a module but I don't know, in which folder I have to download it.
Entering

```
python --version
```

in the terminal, I get 3.7.6

But the IDLE says, I use 3.9.5

I downloaded a module via pip but I can't import it in my IDLE.

Running

```
mdfind pyperclip
```

in terminal shows me, that it is saved in my anaconda library.

**I am confused about the difference of Python version in terminal and in IDLE.
And I also have no idea, how to pip the module (pyperclip) into the version I access with the IDLE.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit off here-and-there but i now understand that:

- The version of python in your terminal and in IDLE is different, and
- Whenever you download an module (lets assume pyperclip) it is saved into your anaconda library.

Looks like they both have different versions of python. try updating python in your terminal and in IDLE. even if they have different versions, unless they are too outdated versions of python they shouldnt be causing you any problem.

And, whenever you download any module, you're unable to find it.

- Firstly, when you download it, try specifying it's folder to be downloaded into an proper directory
- Secondly, if the problem persists, as said, your module is downloaded into the anaconda library, try importing the module from the library (eg: if the name of the library is anaconda, type: `import anaconda.pyperclip`)
- Or, try updating pip as it could be outdated.

I could be wrong here-and-there but worth trying the workarounds said above...